# How to set the check box's checked option persistent,while user switches from one activity class to another

Tags: android, android-widget

i am designing a simple android app,which has a check box displayed in the list view and my application is giving a alarm when the corresponding  check box is checked.But while i am moving from that screen to my home screen and again coming back to my page containing the check box it doesn't show that which check box i checked previously.

Please help me regarding this topic,
than x in advance..

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the data getting saved.  Have you looked at `SharedPreferences`?  Also, post some code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are setting it as checked/unchecked somewhere (like in the `onResume()` or elsewhere) so it's state is reset each time you enter this activity.

If the checked state must persist between app runs, you could store the checkbox state in a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and in the `onResume()` use the [setChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29) method with the value of the preference...

Else you can try not to overwrite anywhere the checkbox state or store it in a class field or something to reset it to the desired value when the activity return to front

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the setting to [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).  In the `onPause()` method of your activity, save the setting.  You can then read the preferences in `onResume()` and re-populate your UI.  Any other `Activity` or `Service` can then read the setting from the preferences and take action accordingly.